# Hibernation doesn't power off the laptop

Tags: hibernate, amd-ryzen

I installed Xubuntu 20.04 to ASUS X412DA laptop on Ryzen 3 CPU.

I've setup hibernation properly and it actually works, but it doesn't power off the laptop.

If I start hibernation from CLI or a menu, the screen goes off but the laptop stays powered.

If I hold the power button and force power off, all is good. When I power it on again, it restores from hibernation.

How can I debug and resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. It seems that there is some problem in S4 sleep mode for this chipset. So I set to skip it and set it to poweroff after suspending to disk.

So edit `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`

Uncomment the line

```
#HibernateMode=platform shutdown
```

to be

```
HibernateMode=shutdown
```

and reboot.

All is fixed.

Comment: With this setting my laptop did not shutdown at all. The battery drained to 0% after the hibernating operations themselves were done. Note that [Debugging hibernation and suspend](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/basic-pm-debugging.html) from kernel.org recommends `platform` mode.

Comment: So do you have a solution? @thorsten?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Nor did I find a way do debug it. Maybe it depends on the kernel support for the particular laptop @anshuman-kumar

Comment: I just turned off Hibernate for Ubuntu. It's a "non solution" solution but my computer doesn't at least freeze on me anymore  (for me the screen used  to remain on the but laptop stop responding to anything and as an added  bonus the fans used to spin at a super high RPM,something that only happened when I play 4K games). I wasn't too keen on changing the kernel as I have no idea what I could end up fudging. Another commenter told me this was possibly the problem with my PC.